# On Hover of a div javascript file should load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div`:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

This `div` only comes up when I hover over a `div`.

I have a `script.js` which should load only on hover of this `div` and not by default.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. Could you provide more details about what you tried, and the result of your research on this?

Comment: I am curious, what does `script.js` do?

Comment: script.js loads an ad banner. I had tried to load via ajax but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use jQuery getScript function

```
$(function() { 
   $(".content").hover(function() {
       $.getScript( "script.js" );
   }); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery, here is the code

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cjnW6/)**

HTML

```
<div class="hoverme">Hover me</div>
<div class="content">horaay, I'm a hidden content</div>
```

CSS

```
.content {
    display:none;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(".hoverme").hover(function() {
    $(".content").stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can load js file on hover of div

```
   <div id="samplediv" onmouseover="loadjsfile()">testing</div>

    function loadjsfile() {
         $.getScript("script.j");
     }
```